# How do I do queryOrdered(bychild) for this?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up my firebase as in the picture, Now I would like to feed my posts with only new posts by comparing each post timestamp, I have written the code below

```
func getRecentPosts(start timestamp: Int? = nil, limit: UInt, completionHandler: @escaping (([Post]) -> Void)){

    let POST_DB_REF: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    var allPosts = POST_DB_REF.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")

    if let latestPostTimestamp = timestamp, latestPostTimestamp > 0 {
        //If the timestamp is specified, we will get the posts with timestamp newer than the given value
        allPosts = allPosts.queryStarting(atValue: latestPostTimestamp + 1, childKey: Post.PostInfoKey.timestamp).queryLimited(toLast: limit)
    } else {
        //Otherwise, we will just get the most recent posts
        allPosts = allPosts.queryLimited(toLast: limit)
    }

    //Call Firebase API to retrieve the latest records
    allPosts.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newPosts: [Post] = []
        for userPosts in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            for eachPost in userPosts.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let postInfo = eachPost.value as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                if let post = Post(postId: eachPost.key, postInfo: postInfo) {
                    newPosts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }

        if newPosts.count > 0 {
            //Order in descending order (i.e. the latest post becomes the first post)
            newPosts.sort(by: {$0.timestamp > $1.timestamp})
        }
        completionHandler(newPosts)
    })
}
```

Here is my firebase config.
[FIREBASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRLC0.png)
This works with the first run, then if I post a new feed it does not get updated, any Ideas ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is getRecentPosts being called? Could the error be that this method isn't being invoked?

Comment: Yes, I am calling this method in my FeedTableViewController where I add new posts.

Comment: Actually, it is called in two methods, in ViewDidLoad and whenever I post something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `allPosts.observeSingleEvent`, you will always get the value from the local Firebase cache. If you always need the latest value from the server, you must use `allPosts.observe` instead which will fire events as soon as the value on the server has changed.

Another option is to disable the cache:

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = false
```